# Will GCM based server and Firebase client (iOS) work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a situation where the server is Google Cloud Messaging based and iOS client code is using Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK. Will the server be able to send the notifications to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work without problems. The server will use the old GCM URLs, but those are compatible with FCM. That's really the only thing server-side that would not specifically be FCM.

I have an FCM-based Android client and a GCM-based server, and it's working well.